# How to secure a Query inside of a GET param?

Tags: php, mysql, security, pdo, get

I need to secure a SQL Query inside an GET param from my website which directly accesses to my database.

The url would be like:

```
   xxx.de/entryAPI.php?query=`city`='Berlin'&...
```

which generates following SQL Query:

```
SELECT * FROM `xyz` WHERE `city`='Berlin' LIMIT 0, 20
```

The table contains much more columns and I need very different queries, so an prepared statement isn't possible for my.

I have an defined set of queries which should be possible, so would it be 
an idea to write the possible queries to an db and the get param has to be validated with this database, which contains all possible queries? Then an URL call only would generate an SQL Query if the query in the get param is also storaged in the database.

Thank you and I hope you understand my problem!

Comment: You should have a limited set of GET parameters `city`, etc. Then build the query based on the passed parameters. Bind the value. You also should URL encode your get parameters so values aren't lost.

Comment: @chris85 This isn't possible because the table contains a huge amount of columns which all need to queried in different ways for different cases.

Comment: You can generate a column safelist with `SELECT 
 COLUMN_NAME
FROM  
 information_schema.COLUMNS
WHERE 
 TABLE_NAME = '[table_name]'
 AND
 COLUMN_NAME = '?'` and use an prepared statement

Comment: You cant just let a user pass whatever they want to your SQL.

Comment: You should start by correctly formatting your query string, `?query=city=Berlin;` should be `?query=&city=Berlin;` Or such.

Comment: @chris85 Sure I know. So my idea would be an whitelist of queries. So if the user writes in an impossible query like ` xxx.de/entryAPI.php?query=`city`='Berlin'; DELTE * FROM Tablename`, which isn't on my whitelist my script wouldn't generate the Query for my db. Is that possible?

Comment: @DanielJanke - you should never allow a user to pass in SQL, it wont work out well for you.

Comment: How are you going to know every city name? The column should be parameter name and the value should be the value being queried. Use a placeholder for the value, and the whitelist for the columns.

Comment: @chris85 The amount of cities is 120, so I know all of them. Ok but sometimes I got much more complex queries like:

`SELECT * FROM 'xyz' WHERE 'city'='Berlin' AND 'foo' > 120 AND 'bar' < 20 OR ...`

How can I put something like this into a get Url? It would be too long.

Comment: Maybe something like `query.php?city=Berlin&gt_foo=120&lt_bar=20` which is no where near to long, your actual current method would be longer. I think the limit for GET request is in the 8k range, so you aren't approaching it in either approach (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2659952/maximum-length-of-http-get-request)

Comment: Please mind that your api may require conditions like "not null", "like", ">", etc. and that will require large design changes. You may try more explicit filters: filter1_col=city&filter1_value=berlin&filter1_cond=like. Also this approach helps distinguish filters with other possible parameters.

Comment: I would use JSON for this.  But it's Non/Trivial

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

You basically have 3 choices

1. Create separate methods that search on something specific. This would be set methods with pre-defined inputs.
2. Make it somewhat flexible but have separate methods.  This would have set methods but with some flexabillity in the inputs.
3. Make it supper flexible so it can handle most queries.

This last one is non-trivial ( meaning hard ) coding wise, but once it's setup it could handle most everything you need.  Not to mention it's "cool" so I will cover that in some detail.

Now what I would do is use JSON, because it's gonna give you way more flexibility structure wise.  You can always use `base64_encode()` or some other encoding to sneak it into the `$_GET` array without issues with the url characters, or you can use `$_POST` for it.  However you want to get it to the server is cool with me.

I would use a schema like this

```
query = {
    "groupOp":"AND",
    "expr":[],
    "group" : [{
           "groupOp":"OR",
           "expr":[{
                "field":"id",
                "op":"eq",
                "value":"2"
            },{
                "field":"id",
                "op":"eq",
                "value":"3"
            }],
            "group" : []
        },{
            "groupOp":"AND",
               "expr":[{
                    "field":"created_date",
                    "op":"gte",
                    "value":"2017-10-01"
                },{
                    "field":"created_date",
                    "op":"lte",
                    "value":"2017-10-31"
                 }],
               "group" : []
        }],
    }
```

Which would roughly work out ( provided a table is supplied )

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    ( id = 2 OR id = 3 )
AND
    (created_date >= "2017-10-01" AND created_date <= "2017-10-31" )
```

Now just to point this out, the `groupOp` and `group` is very important for even simple queries like above.  Compare the above query with this one.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    tbl
WHERE
    id = 2 OR id = 3
AND
    created_date >= "2017-10-01" AND created_date <= "2017-10-31"
```

*-note- You can use other `$_GET` parameters for things like the sort order, sort index, table, limits etc..  ( like `?sort_index=id&sort_order=DESC&query=AJGEDC` )*

The groups denote sets of `( )`, without them this second query has a whole different meaning.  This is an Exclusive OR, because we need to compare the IDs as a set, then compare the date range.  Without that we could match `id=2` without the date range.

So now that I explained the theory you will have to write something ( probably a recursive function ) to compile the JSON into SQL

The basic rules would be.

- group: a set of expressions ( expr )
- groupOp: how expressions relate to one another within a group,and how nested groups relate to those expressions
- expr: a set of query segments
- field: the name of the column you want to compare
- op: how the field is related to the data, for example:
  *eq = equal, gte = greater then or equal, gt = greater then* etc...
- value: the value to compare against.

A few things to note for Security:

- Never ever concatenate user supplied strings into your sql, without checking them first. If you do that you open yourself up to all kinds of Sql Injection nastyness.  So take their column names from `field` and make sure they exist in the table the query is for before using them.
- Use something like `SHOW TABLES` to get a list of tables from the DB, then compare user supplied tables with this list.
- Use something like `SHOW COLUMNS FROM table` to get the table schema, then compare user supplied columns with this list.
- Always use Prepared Statements. So build your query with placeholders, and an array of inputs. Then prepare and execute the query.  such as `SELECT ... WHERE id = :expr1..` and `[':expr1' => 2]`.
- If you allow sorting and limit, same thing applies don't concatenate, anything. Don't take shortcuts on security.

One other example with nested groups

```
query = {
"groupOp":"AND",
"expr":[],
"group" : [{
       "groupOp":"OR",
       "expr":[{
            "field":"id",
            "op":"eq",
            "value":"2"
        },{
            "field":"id",
            "op":"eq",
            "value":"3"
        }],
        "group" : [{
            "groupOp":"AND",
            "expr":[{
                "field":"id",
                "op":"in",
                "value":[5,6,7]
            },{
                "field":"cat",
                "op":"eq",
                "value":'product'
            }
        }]
    }],
}
```

With this being the SQL

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
    (
        id=2
            OR
        id=3 
            OR
        (
            id IN( 5,6,7 ) 
                AND
            cat = 'product'
        )
    )
```

This query would find records with an `id` of `2,3` OR records with `id` Of `5,6,7` **And** a `cat` of "product".

You can also do them simple too:

```
{
    "expr":[{
            "field":"id",
            "op":"eq",
            "value":"2"
    }]
}
```

With SQL like this

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM
    table
WHERE
   id=2
```

So you can see by using JSON, we can have the complexity we would need for this, which would be hard to achieve using just URL query parameters.  And trust me, something like this will need that added level of complexity at some time, so you might as well build it in to begin with.

Even with that added level of detail, you will still probably want multiple methods to deal with things like Joins and multiple tables.  I don't know your exact use case, so maybe you only need it for one table.  But, it can start to get real messy if you put to much detail in it.  It's a balancing act.

I've built things like this before and they work pretty well, most the time it's pretty purpose built so I don't have anything that doesn't have a bunch of dependencies I can give you. And I don't have the time to write the entire thing up for you right now, as I have to change this light fixture ... long story.

Anyway, hope those Ideas help ( good Luck! )